# Get the time spent by a process on Linux

Tags: linux, postgresql

I want to measure the time it takes to backup a PostgresSql database, I know I can do `time pg_dump ....`, but what if I already launched the pg_dump command?.

The process already took more than half an hour, and I don't want to break it right know. I'm pretty sure it will take one more hour (and I'll be at home at that time). I would like to know tomorrow how much time it took.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are writing this to file, do you? File modification time would be your answer.

Comment: simple answers are always awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Just show start time

```
ps -ax  -o cmd,lstart | grep pg_dump
```

Or timestamp

```
ls --time-style=+%s -ld /proc/PROCESS_PID
```

Or secs elapsed

```
ls --time-style=+%s -ld /proc/PROCESS_PID | cut -d " " -f6 | \
xargs echo "`date +%s` - $1" | bc
```

Answer (score 2):

find the pid of your process, say it 999

run this:

```
while ps -p 999 -o pid; do  date; sleep 20; done
```

in a shell. the above will quit when your process is done.

you can sleep more if granularity you want is bigger.